# How to make a virtual attribute be a boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to get my virtual attribute that is a boolean to work. In this example, lets call the virtual boolean field `children`:

**models/parent.rb**

```
Parent
 attr_accessible :children
 attr_accessor :children
 validates_inclusion_of :children, :in => [true, false]

 def self.children=(boolean)
 end

end
```

**parents/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :children %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Right now when I try to use it, (create a parent) it gives me the error

```
Children is not included in the list
```

when the validation comes up.

How do I write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The param you get from the browser is a String (based on your comment to the other answer: «Instead of true and false though its using 0 and 1."parent"=>{"children"=>"1"}»). Your validation checks whether it is a boolean.

I suggest the following solution:

First, Remove your `def self.children=()` method, it does nothing at all in your current implementation (it is a class method and never called).

Then, implement a custom accessor that converts the String param into a boolean:

```
class Parent
  attr_reader :children

  def children=(string_value)
    @children = (string_value == '1')
  end

  validates_inclusion_of :children, :in => [true, false]
end
```

With that your original validation should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to understand ruby, appreciate it!

Comment: But still ugly. There should be boolean_attr_accessor implemented somewhere. If not, it's amazing :)

Answer (score 12):

Rails 5 has now added the `attribute` method for this.

```
class Parent
  attribute :children, :boolean
end
```

It's officially called "attributes API" and you can find the documentation here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the params[:children] is a string? and it expected a boolean.

Comment: When I look at the form its actually a `hidden` input. Hmmmmm..... i.e. `<input name="parent[children]" type="hidden" value="0">`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you check the console and see the params, I think children will be a string not a boolean. So the validation doesn't match

true != "true"

Comment: I see now. Instead of true and false though its using 0 and 1."parent"=>{"children"=>"1"}. Now I put this validation instead: `validates_inclusion_of :children, :in => [1, 0]` but why doesn't it work? Or even better, can I change it to use true and false?

Comment: One solution should be to use a custom validation => http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually define a children 'setter' method, because that's exactly what attr_accessor does automatically. Try removing your def self.children=(boolean) method.